# How to display both month and year datepicker and full calender datepicker in one text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have search functionality in my application. In that search functionality, I have one text field and one drop down selection box and the search button for action.

In drop down selection box I have 5 selection statements i.e,"By project code" it's a string, "By Date" is a date-picker with full calendar, "By Month" is a date-picker only with month and year,"By supplier" is a string,"By Description" is a string.

Here when I select By Date I need to display full calendar date picker as showing in the below image

[image]

, when I select By Month I need to display only month and year date-picker as showing in the below image
[image]

This is the code I am using for this functionality but it's not working properly

**Javascript**

```
function showDatepicker() {
    var podate = $("#search_type").val();

     if(podate == "By Date"){
          $('#search_string').datepicker( {
              dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
              showOn: "both",
              buttonImage: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/calendar.png",
              buttonImageOnly: true
            }).click(function(){
                $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').show();
            });
     }else if(podate == "By Month"){
         alert("kjhkjhkj");
         //$('#search_string').attr('id', 'search_string1'); 
        // $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').attr('class', 'ui-datepicker-calendar1');
         $('#search_string').datepicker( {
             showOn: "both",
              buttonImage: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/calendar.png",
              buttonImageOnly: true,
             changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                dateFormat: 'M yy',
                onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, widget) {
                    $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').hide();
                },
                onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
                    var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                },
            }).click(function(){
                $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').hide();
            });
     }else {
         $(".ui-datepicker-trigger").hide();
         $("#ui-datepicker-div").hide();
         $("#search_string").val(""); 

     }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="search_form" id="search_form" method="post" action="<%=request.getRequestURI()%>">
    <div><input type="text" name="emp_email" value="<%=session.getAttribute("emp_email")%>" id="emp_email" style="display: none;"></div>
        <table width="50%" border="0" class="search_tbl" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" style="margin-left: 252px;">
            <tr>
                <td width="70">Search for</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="search_string" id="search_string" size="48">
                        <select name="search_type" id="search_type" onchange="showDatepicker();">
                            <option value="By Project Code"<%=(search_type==null || search_type.equals("By Project Code"))?"selected":"" %>>By Project Code</option>
                            <option value="By Date"<%=(search_type != null && search_type.equals("By Date"))?"selected":"" %>>By Date</option>
                            <option value="By Month"<%=(search_type != null && search_type.equals("By Month"))?"selected":"" %>>By Month</option>
                            <option value="By Supplier"<%=(search_type != null && search_type.equals("By Supplier"))?"selected":"" %>>By Supplier</option>
                            <option value="By Description"<%=(search_type != null && search_type.equals("By Description"))?"selected":"" %>>By Description</option>
                        </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" class="form-button"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Please help me

Comment: "it's not working properly" is not a good enough explanation of the problem. What happens when you try to run this code?

Comment: 1.if i select By date for the first time the date-picker displaying full calendar and then for selection of By month also its displaying same calendar only.2. if i select By month for the first time the date-picker displaying Month and Year calendar and then for selection of By date also its displaying same calendar i.e, Month and year calender

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `.datepicker` with different options on the same element, you need to destroy it before invoking it again. You can check to see whether it has already been assigned with the jQuery UI `hasDatepicker` class.

```
if ( "#search_string" ).hasClass('hasDatepicker'){   
$( "#search_string" ).datepicker( "destroy" );
};
// Assign new datepicker object
```

Alternatively, assign `.datepicker` to different elements.

```
$('#element_1').datepicker( {
//options
});

$('#element_2').datepicker( {
//options
});
```